# Getting IllegalAccessError warning

Tags: selenium

I'm trying to write my first program in selenium-java but in a short program of few lines I'm getting following error:

*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class org.openqa.selenium.os.ExecutableFinder from class org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.locateFirefoxBinariesFromPlatform(FirefoxBinary.java:418)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.(FirefoxBinary.java:108)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.toExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:108)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:104)
    at com.packt.selenium.chapter1.NavigateToAUrl.main(NavigateToAUrl.java:12)*

My code is:

```
package com.packt.selenium.chapter1;   
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;    
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class NavigateToAUrl 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was caused by having different versions of selenium artifacts on the classpath.

I use gebish: `org.grails.plugins:geb:1.1.1` which depends on:

- `org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:2.53.1`
- `org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:2.53.1`

on the other hand I tried to use
`org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:3.4.0`

After upgrading `selenium-api`, `selenium-remote-driver` and `selenium-support` to version `3.4.0` everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

To work with Selenium 3.4.0 and Mozilla Firefox browser 53.x you need to download the latest geckodriver v0.16.1 from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases). Save it in your machine & provide the absolute path of the geckodriver. This code executes fine with some simple tweak to your own code.

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I have Selenium 3.4.0 & Mozilla Firefox 53.x. I have tried it with geckodriver v0.16.1 but it is still showing same problem.

Comment: @Punk23 Can update the Question with your updated code & the error stacktrace?

Answer (score -1):

Try below code :

```
package com.packt.selenium.chapter1;  
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class sample {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        WebDriver driver;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", "C:\\geckodriver.exe");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(160, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://google.com");

    }
}
```

**Ensure that** :

1) `Selenium server standalone jar` file is added to your project
2) `Client combined jar` file is added to your project which comes with selenium java jar files package.
3) `Geckodriver path` is correct and `geckodriver.exe` is present at the mentioned location.

Don't stick to main method approach in selenium. Integrate `TestNG` along with selenium and then write scripts. You will get many additional functionality if you use [TestNG](http://www.guru99.com/all-about-testng-and-selenium.html). Its recommended !