# Unable to Launch any browser using selenium webdriver

Tags: eclipse, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use eclipse to run Selenium web-driver automation but unable to open a browser window. Debug logs are showing that there is no error and I am successfully able to retrieve title of the web page as shown below:

```
try {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/Users/shankar.sharma/Downloads/chrome-driver/geckodriver");

        DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        cap.setCapability("marionette", true);

        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        options.addPreference("log", "{level: error}");

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.navigate().to("http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/");
        String appTitle = driver.getTitle();
        System.out.println("Application title is :: "+appTitle);
        driver.quit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception:"+e.getMessage());
    }
```

***Debug Logs:***
1496221115902   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:39119
1496221116097   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin with args ["-marionette"]
1496221117678   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 63210
May 31, 2017 2:28:38 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
2017-05-31 14:28:38.036 plugin-container[55325:3295542] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x9c3b, name = 'com.apple.tsm.portname'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
2017-05-31 14:28:38.038 plugin-container[55325:3295542] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x9f03, name = 'com.apple.CFPasteboardClient'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
Application title is :: Downloads
1496221129876   Marionette  INFO    New connections will no longer be accepted

But browser window is not opening. I have also tried with chrome driver but that is also not working. I am using below configurations :

- Selenium Web-driver : 3.4.0
- LGecko driver : v0.16.0

Any ideas about the cause why this is happening?

Comment: your geckodriver property is incorrect.

Comment: @SiddheshKalgaonkar I think path is correct. If I add .exe extension, then it stops working.

Comment: i edited my comment and if you add .exe it should not stop working .please refer my answer

Comment: If I change anything in this path, it gives "The driver executable does not exist" error.

Comment: which version of firefox / chrome browser you are using?

Comment: @santhoshkumar Firefox Version : 47.0, Selenium Web-Driver : 3.4.0

Comment: kindly update the firefox to the latest version... Selenium 3.4 may not be compatabile with firefox 47.. Go with Selenium 3.40, firefox..,53

Comment: @santhoshkumar I have already tried with Firefox 53.0 also but still no success.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145552/discussion-between-shankar-sharma-and-santhosh-kumar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked the same in my mac but its working fine for me.. Below is the default code for which i can see the browser has been getting launched automatically...

```
 public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/santhoshkumar/Documents/Softwares/chromedriver"); 
   driver.manage().windows().maximize();
   WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
   driver.get("http://facebook.com"); 
   System.out.println(driver.getTitle()); 
}
```

Since this is not working for you.. Try to use chromeoptions..

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/santhoshkumar/Documents/Softwares/chromedriver"); 
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); 
  options.addArguments("start-maximized"); 
  options.addArguments("--start-fullscreen");
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options); 
  driver.get("http://facebook.com"); 
  System.out.println(driver.getTitle()); 
}
```

Hope this helps you. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, actually it was working but browser was not getting opened. Not it worked perfectly. Thanks for your quick help.

Answer (score 0):

Go through my answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43733386/getting-illegalaccesserror-warning/43735757#43735757) link and make sure that your browser `firefox version` is below `48.0`
Enjoy :)

Comment: I tried with firefox 47.0 but that is also not helping.

Comment: Don't panic .Follow step by step and after that show me what you have done and if you have any doubts regarding configuration then ask here

Comment: As I am able to see in debug logs that selenium is able to execute the code written but somehow it's not able to open the browser. I tried with chrome also and it's the same problem. So, It seems that there is some other configuration which I am missing. Can you suggest if there is any configuration for browser in selenium?

Comment: Just write my code and ensure the 3 things which I have mentioned and then let me know. Your code is not upto the mark

Comment: Okay edit your code above and list down all the configurations you did before running the script. I am more interested in that because i will automatically come to know where you went wrong